# Print log messages from 2 classes placed under same package hierarchy to 2 different files

Tags: java, logging, log4j, rollingfileappender

I have 2 Java classes inside the same package. I want to log messages from these 2 classes into 2 different log files.

> The log messages should not be repeated in any of these two files.

I am using the following log4j.properties file:

```
# Set root category priority to DEBUG and its appender to CONSOLE and LOGFILE_ENGINE.
log4j.rootCategory=DEBUG, LOGFILE_ENGINE, SYNC_HANDLER


log4j.additivity.LOGFILE_ENGINE = false
log4j.additivity.SYNC_HANDLER = false


log4j.category.org.jboss=ERROR
log4j.category.org.apache.axis=ERROR
log4j.category.org.springframework=ERROR
log4j.category.org.hibernate=ERROR
log4j.category.org.jgroups=ERROR
log4j.category.org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader=OFF
log4j.logger.net.sourceforge.stripes=ERROR
log4j.logger.net.sf.ehcache=ERROR
log4j.additivity.org.jboss.cache=false
log4j.logger.org.quartz=ERROR

# LOGFILE_ENGINE is set to be a File appender using a PatternLayout.
log4j.appender.LOGFILE_ENGINE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.LOGFILE_ENGINE.File=${catalina.home}/logs/file1.log
log4j.appender.LOGFILE_ENGINE.Append=true
log4j.appender.LOGFILE_ENGINE.maxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.LOGFILE_ENGINE.maxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.LOGFILE_ENGINE.Threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.LOGFILE_ENGINE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.LOGFILE_ENGINE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss.SSS a} %-5p %c - %m%n


log4j.appender.SYNC_HANDLER=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.SYNC_HANDLER.File=${catalina.home}/logs/file2.log
log4j.appender.SYNC_HANDLER.Append=true
log4j.appender.SYNC_HANDLER.maxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.SYNC_HANDLER.maxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.SYNC_HANDLER.Threshold=DISASTER#PackageName.className
log4j.appender.SYNC_HANDLER.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.SYNC_HANDLER.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss.SSS a} %-5p %c - %m%n
```

`DISASTER#PackageName.className` is custom level I have made by extending the `Level` class of the `org.apache.log4j`

**My PROBLEM 1.** log messages from file2.log are getting repeated into the file1.log file.

**2.** Is It possible to do class based logging through log4j.

No need to mention that I am naive in regard to `Log4j`....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a **solution** to my problem.

I created a custom log level for my class for which I want separate logs.

I tried the following log4j configuration:

```
log4j.rootCategory=DEBUG, LOGFILE_ENGINE

log4j.category.packageName.className = DEBUG, packageName.className.syncLogger
log4j.additivity.packageName.className= false

log4j.appender.LOGFILE_ENGINE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.LOGFILE_ENGINE.File=${catalina.home}/logs/file1.log
.....................

log4j.appender.packageName.className.syncLogger=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.packageName.className.syncLogger.File=${catalina.home}/logs/file2.log
log4j.appender.packageName.className.syncLogger.Threshold=DISASTER#packageName.SyncLogLevel
.....................
```

And, I created the logger reference as follows:

```
private static final String FQCN = className.class.getName();
private static final String SYNC_LOGGER_NAME = FQCN + ".syncLogger";
public static customLoggingClassName syncLogger = Logger.getLogger(SYNC_LOGGER_NAME);
```

Below is the Custom Level Class(**SyncLogLevel**) for creating a custom Level (**DISASTER**):

```
public class SyncLogLevel extends Level{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public SyncLogLevel(int level, String levelStr, int syslogEquivalent) {
        super(level, levelStr, syslogEquivalent);
    }
    public static SyncLogLevel toLevel(int val, Level defaultLevel) {
        return DISASTER;
    }

    public static SyncLogLevel toLevel(String sArg, Level defaultLevel) {
        return DISASTER;
    }
    public static final SyncLogLevel DISASTER = new SyncLogLevel(60000, "DISASTER", 0);

}
```

After this you have to do your logging in the desired class as follows:

```
syncLogger.log(SyncLogLevel.DISASTER, "Log Message");
```

At the end all the log messages called from syncLogger with the log level "DISASTER" will go to a separate file(file2.log)

After doing all this, All my logs go into desired files separately.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is something like:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, file1, file2

log4j.appender.file1=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
...

log4j.appender.file2=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
...

log4j.logger.my.package.MyClassA=DEBUG, file1
log4j.additivity.my.package.MyClassA=false

log4j.logger.my.package.MyClassB=DEBUG, file2
log4j.additivity.my.package.MyClassB=false
```

Which means that you can use the class name in the logger. Hope this helps!

Comment: I am sorry but I have tried this already and it throws error. Some Bean Creation Exception.

Comment: Please refer to my answer below. Thanks.